# canvas.toDataURL not working on Android >4 devices (but on Android 2)

Tags: android, cordova, canvas, ionic-framework, todataurl

I'm building an App with Cordova/Ionic.
The user can manipulate his gallery-fotos, which are then displayed on the app.

The problem I face right now is, that after the manipulation, the images are not shown on Android >4 devices (Android 4, Android 5, Android 6, etc.). There's just a "image-not-found"-image visible. But everything works as expected on Android 2.x devices.

Are there any significant changes between these versions?

The manipulation is done with [this plugin](https://github.com/JrSchild/jr-crop).

My code looks like the following (**index.html**)

```
<img src="{{!!image.img11 ? image.img11.src : 'img/layout/placeholder.png'}}" ng-cloak>
```

**App.js**

```
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail,
      {
        quality: 30,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        targetWidth: imagePickerWidth,
        targetHeight: imagePickerHeight,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        allowEdit: false
      });

      function onSuccess(imageURI) {
        self.crop(resolve, reject, scope, imageURI, type, width, height, tabs);

        /* JR-CROP MANIPULATION */

        scope.image.img11 = new Image();
        scope.image.img11.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that on Android bigger than 5 (5,6,7) there is a need for an `security-policy` in the `index.html` `header`.

Just add the following:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:;">
...
</head>
```

This allows `base64` encoded images to be displayed.